# SQL join to an alias column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Not sure if this is possible but I'm trying to join to an alias column in SQL Server.

Is it possible to change the JOIN below?

```
JOIN 
    #LOGFILE ON #CSIQUESTIONLOG.LogSeqNo = #LOGFILE.Seq 
             AND #LOGFILE.Contcode = 'WCM'
```

to

```
JOIN 
    #LOGFILE ON #CSIQUESTIONLOG.LogSeqNo = #LOGFILE.[SEQ2] 
             AND #LOGFILE.Contcode = 'WCM'
```

So it joins to the `SEQ2` column - not the `SEQ` column, and so I only have to run one query

Sample data below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CSIQUESTIONLOG') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #CSIQUESTIONLOG

SELECT * 
INTO #CSIQUESTIONLOG 
FROM (VALUES ('BA', '2017-01-01','123451', '185', 2),
             ('BA', '2017-01-01','123452', '185', 4),
             ('BA', '2017-01-01','123453', '184', 1),
             ('BA', '2017-01-01','123454', '183', 3),
             ('BA', '2017-01-01','123455', '182', 5),
             ('BA', '2017-01-01','123456', '181', 0),
             ('BA', '2017-01-01','123457', '182', 1),
             ('BA', '2017-01-01','7684417', '180', 2)) d (Dealer, Created, Logseqno, CSIseqno, Answer)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LOGFILE') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #LOGFILE

SELECT * 
INTO #LOGFILE 
FROM (VALUES (7684417, 'BA', 498, 'WCM', 1261723),
             (7669984, 'BA', 38, 'CSI', 1261723),
             (7685141, 'BA', 400, 'WCM', 1261750),
             (7686369, 'BA', 193, 'CSI', 1261750),
             (7692571, 'BA', 401, 'WCM', 1262289),
             (7700336, 'BA', 38, 'CSI', 1262289)) d (Seq, Dealer, OpNum, Contcode, ContSeqNo)

SELECT 
    a.*, x.Seq AS [SEQ2]
FROM 
    #LOGFILE a
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT Seq
     FROM #LOGFILE b
     WHERE b.ContSeqNo = a.ContSeqNo AND b.ContCode = 'CSI') x
```

Final query:

```
SELECT 
    #CSIQUESTIONLOG.Created, #CSIQUESTIONLOG.CSIseqno, 
    #LOGFILE.OpNum,
    COUNT (*) AS TOTAL
FROM 
    #CSIQUESTIONLOG
JOIN 
    #LOGFILE ON #CSIQUESTIONLOG.LogSeqNo = #LOGFILE.Seq 
             AND #LOGFILE.Contcode = 'WCM'
GROUP BY 
    #CSIQUESTIONLOG.Created, #CSIQUESTIONLOG.CSIseqno, #LOGFILE.OpNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your final query there ins no column `Seq2`. Those are two seperate queries, and thus, they can't interact with each other.

Without the expected result set, I've just chanegd the SQL to what I *believe* you're after. If it's not, post your expected result set.

```
SELECT QL.Created,
       QL.CSIseqno,
       LF2.OpNum, --Not sure if this should be LF1, or LF2. Guessed 2
       COUNT (*) AS TOTAL
FROM #CSIQUESTIONLOG QL
     JOIN #LOGFILE LF1 ON QL.LogSeqNo = LF1.Seq AND LF1.Contcode = 'WCM'
     JOIN #LOGFILE LF2 ON LF1.ContSeqNo = LF2.ContSeqNo AND LF2.ContCode = 'CSI'
GROUP BY QL.Created, --You were completely missing your GROUP BY
         QL.CSIseqno,
         LF2.OpNum;
```